# Customized Not Equal Symbol

Tags: symbols, math-operators

How can I create the following symbols, or is there it? I didn't find it?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\newcommand{\mynoteq}{\mathrel{\text{$\ooalign{$=$\cr\hidewidth$\mycross$\hidewidth\cr}$}}}
\newcommand{\mycross}{%
   \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{1.3}{$\times$}}}
   }

\begin{document}
  $ a \mynoteq d_{a \mynoteq d_{a \mynoteq d}}$

  $ a \mynoteq d^{a \mynoteq d^{a \mynoteq d}}$

  $ a = d$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is working. But is it possible big \times? This is a little small \times. @Harish Kumar,

Comment: @Özgür Give me some time. It is easy and possible.

Comment: @Özgür Please see the update. You may change the number in `\scalebox` as you wish.

Comment: My question is closed for me. Thanks. @Harish Kumar

Comment: +1. The outer pair of `$` symbols in the definition of `\mycross` seem unnecessary, though.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for spotting the remnant. Corrected. :)

Answer (score 4):

With picture mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nnoteq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\nnot@eq\relax}}
\newcommand{\nnot@eq}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1=$}%
  \vcenter{\rlap{%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\wd0}%
    \begin{picture}(1,1)
    \linethickness{0.4pt}%
    \ifx#1\scriptstyle
      \linethickness{.9\@wholewidth}%
    \else
      \ifx#1\scriptscriptstyle
        \linethickness{.75\@wholewidth}%
      \fi
    \fi
    \roundcap
    \put(0.1,0.1){\line(1,1){0.8}}
    \put(0.1,0.9){\line(1,-1){0.8}}
    \end{picture}%
  }}%
  {=}%
}

\begin{document}

$a\nnoteq b_{\nnoteq_{\nnoteq}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This could probably be optimized a little more:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{centernot,graphicx}

\newcommand{\xequal}{\mathrel{\mathchoice
  {\centernot{\reflectbox{$\neq$}}}
  {\centernot{\reflectbox{$\neq$}}}
  {\centernot{\reflectbox{$\scriptstyle\neq$}}}
  {\centernot{\reflectbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\neq$}}}}}

\begin{document}

$a = b \xequal c^{d = e \xequal f^{g = h \xequal i}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't know that package. Good for me. @Werner.